# Pygame only draws 1/4 of the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know why this is happening. I've tested on other computers and it works fine. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Code below, didn't think it mattered as it worked on other computers.

```
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Pixelites")
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT), 0, 32)

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
tiles=defaultTiles(surface,WIDTH,HEIGHT)

while True:
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pass
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    for t in tiles:
        t.draw(surface)
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(1000)
```

Comment: Can you please show us some code, like where you set up the drawing area, etc?

Comment: What on earth makes you think we know whats wrong? You haven't posted a single detail.

Comment: Okay done. More clear hopefully.

Comment: Python, Pygame version? OS version?

Comment: I'm really curious how in the world the application is rendering on top of the OS's title bar.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't update the surface. Oops.